# Add trait to extend builtin types

Tags: rust

I'm trying to extend the Iterator trait with a custom function:

```rs
pub trait CustomTrait<T> : Iterator<Item=T> where Self: Sized, Self: 'static {
    #[inline]
    fn custom_function(self) -> Result<Box<dyn Iterator>, Err> {
        let boxed = Box::new(self);
        do_something(boxed)
    }
}
```

It's compiles correctly. However, when I go to call my new trait on a iterator, the compiler complains about it not being implemented for the iterator. (I have tried `std::ops::Range` and `std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`.)

I was able to get each function call working for individual struct types with lines such as below:

```rs
impl CustomTrait<u64> for std::ops::Range<u64> {}
```

However, I assume there must be a way that I can get my trait definition to apply to all Iterables without having to manually implement it for each struct that implements the Iterable trait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you *extend* a trait, you basically create a new trait that also guarantees that it has all the methods defined by the trait it's extending.

What it *not* does is automatically implement any of those methods for the trait you're extending.

In addition to what you already did, you actually need to *implement* your trait *for* Iterator:

```rust
impl<T> CustomTrait<T> for Iterator<Item=T> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: No I did not, Thank!  For future reference, In my case I had to adapt it a bit due to some of the code I wasn't showing causing a compilation error around the Iterator having a dynamic size:

`impl<T, V> CustomTrait<V> for T where T : Iterator<Item=V>, T: 'static {}`